# How to use OS-dependent function in Go?

Tags: go, setrlimit

I encountered this issue when running my program on Mac:

```
Error: open <filename>: too many open files in system
```

After some digging it seems this issue can be fixed by increasing the limit using `syscall.Setrlimit()` function: https://pkg.go.dev/syscall#Setrlimit

However when I try to use it my IDE complains that the function doesn't exist. I'm developing on windows and it seems this function doesn't exist there. How can I fix this? I need to be able to compile the program for windows, mac and linux from the same source code.

Comment: That's an IDE issue, not Go's. The reason is that the `syscall` package contains OS-dependent code, so basically the IDE parses its contents for Windows, and the compler, which you run with `GOOS=darwin` sees completely different contents. Having said that, I would hint at that you're trying to solve this problem the wrong way: its not your program's business to tweak these limits (they exist for a reason and are enforced externally). Instead, if your program really needs a non-default limit, make sure it's being run with the increased limit (and document that).

Comment: Increasing the limit is too high of a hurdle for inexperienced users and would make my program useless for them so this is not possible. Also on Windows go build of course fails with `undefined: syscall.Setrlimit` so it's not just IDE issue, it breaks build as well.

Comment: «…it's not just IDE issue, it breaks build as wel»–I do not quite understand you. You say you're building on Windows for MacOS; this means you _have to_ build with `GOOS=darwin`. Do you mean you do exactly that and the build stll fails? On my system running `GOOS=darwin go doc syscall` lists `Setrlimit`, so that symbol is available on MacOS.

Comment: I said I'm building on Windows for all systems. When I build for Mac I indeed use `GOOS=darwin` but I need to be able to build for windows as well.

Comment: «Increasing the limit is too high of a hurdle for inexperienced users…»–that's relatable but I think I have failed to get my point across (due to brewity): you cannot use `setrlimit()` (or other means) to raise any limit higher that it is really set. You can only raise the so-called "soft" limit up to (and including) the matching "hard" limit, and they are not usually too far away from each other (though, I'm not experienced with the default settings for the number of open files limit on MacOS).

Comment: «I need to be able to build for windows as well»–Windows does not support `setrlimit`; it's a purely Unix-y thing. So in fact you have two questions in one.

Comment: Still, I advise to think on what I said regarding these limits: they do have default settings on different systems but 1) they are different on different systems (and for OSes based on LInux, they can easily be different between distros and even versions of the same distro); 2) they can be changed by system administrators / system policies. Both these facts mean you cannot expect a call to `setrlimit` to set that limit to a file _you want it to._

Comment: Didn't know about the soft-limit and hard-limit thing, that will indeed require a bit more research on my part. However my main question is still the same: "How to use a function that only exists on some OS while preserving the ability to build for other systems as well?"

Comment: "How to use a function that only exists on some OS while preserving the ability to build for other systems as well?"–that one is easy: <https://pkg.go.dev/go/build#hdr-Build_Constraints>. Say, with `setrlimit`, you'd usually have a `thing_unix.go` and `thing_windows.go` providing the same function, which in the former case would call `syscall.Setrlimit`, and in the latter–do nothing or call some Win32 API-specific thing.

Comment: Re. soft, hard limits and `ulimit`, start [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29579/43156) for instance.